# Long integer to readable string

Tags: c#, math, decimal-point

I want to be able to have very long integers to be converted to a readable string

This goes from 1500 (1.50k) to 12.500.000.000 being 12.50b and so on to unreadable numbers that will be labeled as A then B etc.

Now I'm pretty sure there's a nifty piece of logic that says if the string length of the integer is 9 the dots should be on place 3 and 6 or something.

My math(and its programmable logic) is non-existent for me so can anyone help me out?

This is my messy and non-reusable attempt now:

```
int val = 150050004;
string theValue = val.ToString();
int valLength = theValue.Length;

string newVal = theValue;
if (valLength == 7) {
    newVal = theValue.Substring(0, 1) +"."+ theValue.Substring(1, 2);
}

if (valLength == 8) {
    newVal = theValue.Substring(0, 2) +"."+ theValue.Substring(2, 2);
}

if (valLength == 9) {
    newVal = theValue.Substring(0, 3) +"."+ theValue.Substring(3, 2);
}

if (valLength > 6 && valLength < 10) {
    newVal = newVal + "m";
}
```

Where **newVal** outputs `150.05m`

Comment: I think  using `m` for million is confusing, since it'd the SI prefix for 1/1000.

Comment: It's more to make an example, really. It should work on all letters be it K, T, B, M etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to break with "." :

```
NumberFormatInfo numFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
numFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
numFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

long val = 12345678912345;
String result = val.ToString("#,##0",numFormat);
```

For adding suffixed info, do this :

```
String result = null;
if (val / 1000000000 > 1)
    result = val.ToString("#,##0,#,,B",numFormat);
else if (val / 1000000 > 1)
    result = val.ToString("#,##0,#,M", numFormat);
else if (val / 1000 > 1)
    result = val.ToString("#,##0,#K", numFormat);
else
    result = val.ToString("#,##0", numFormat);
```

Comment: That seems to be for decimals. I think: `"#,##0"`

Comment: I'm getting a `error CS0103: The name String' does not exist in the current context` error?

Comment: You are right, it's a ","

Comment: Ah, got it workign with `using System;`(Now my `Random` is broke though?). Nonetheless; the string is very readable like this. Can I now just Substring it to a lesser value easily? Like 150.05M instead of 150,050,004?

Comment: Yes you can, i updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I can just keep this up with A-Z after B(for example)? How do I know which of the strings is best used to get the result? Since my val gives 0b that one's out of the question while 150m seems pretty accurate. So how do I decide which string suits the best purpose for this string's length?

Comment: I update again the answer

Comment: `10500` becomes 11k in the current code by the way. Instead of 10.5k. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, because there's no placeholder for the last part, so it rounds up. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: This results in 10.500k. Quite a useless "k" than. haha. I'm so sorry I'm such a noob btw :D

Comment: Take a look on the post marked as duplicate